# 400 Bad Request - JavaScript App calling Custom wp-json endpoint

Tags: functions, actions, api, rest-api

I have successfully created a new endpoint/route and can view it via `wp-json`. Not only that, I can successfully make a post request to this endpoint externally from the browser using the Restlet Client. My endpoint handles `json` within the body of the request, transforms and edits the data, then makes an external api call, then sends new data back to the client from the external api.

However, when I run an application on my wordpress site that calls this api, I get `400 Bad Request`. I handle errors in many places within my function, and send back specific error messages based on types of errors that can occur in the data and I can't seem to find where this is coming from. I have set `WP_DEBUG` to `true`, and I'm stuck.

I think it may have to do with handling the `pre-flight` request but not sure.

Can you help me find the error?

**PreFlight Handling**

```
function handle_preflight() {
    header("Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, max-age=0"); //HTTP 1.1
    header("Pragma: no-cache"); //HTTP 1.0
    header("Expires: Sat, 26 Jul 1997 05:00:00 GMT"); // Date in the past
    header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *"); // change * to the known origin once this is put into place
    header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST, PUT, PATCH, DELETE, OPTIONS");
    header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Content-Type");
    header('Access-Control-Max-Age: 50');
    header("Content-Type: application/json");

    if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'OPTIONS') {
        header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers: X-Requested-With, Content-Type");
        http_response_code(200);
        exit();
    }
}

add_action( 'init', 'handle_preflight' );
```

**Init REST endpoint**

```
add_action( 'rest_api_init', function() {
    $version = '1';
    $namespace = "cbngiving/v".$version;
    $base = "giving";
    register_rest_route( $namespace, "/" . $base, array(
        'methods' => 'POST, OPTIONS',
        'callback'=> 'proxy_data'
    ));
});
```

**CALLBACK**

```
function proxy_data($request) {
    $data = $request->get_json_params();
    if(is_null($data)) {
        $response = new WP_REST_Response(array('statusText' => "Bad Request - Your request is missing parameters. Please verify and resubmit.",
        "origin" => "Bad Request from App to Proxy"));
        $response->set_status(400);
        return $response;
    } else {
        $mode = $data['mode'];
        $data['APIAccessID'] = ''; // to be added later
        $data['UrlReferrer'] = $_SERVER["HTTP_REFERRER"];
        $data['ClientBrowser'] = $_SERVER["HTTP_USER_AGENT"];
        $service_url_local = "PRIVATE ENDPOINT< NOT CAUSING ERROR!";
        $service_url_secure = "PRIVATE ENDPOINT< NOT CAUSING ERROR!";
        $service_url = $mode === "production" ? $service_url_secure : $service_url_local;
        unset($data['mode']);
        $proxy_response = wp_remote_post($service_url, array(
            'headers' => array(                                                                          
                'Content-Type' => 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
                'Accept' => 'application/json; charset=utf-8'
            ),
            'body' => json_encode($data)
        ));
        $proxy_response_code = wp_remote_retrieve_response_code( $proxy_response );
        $proxy_response_body = wp_remote_retrieve_body( $proxy_response );
        if ($proxy_response_code >=200 and $proxy_response_code < 300) {
            $response = new WP_REST_Response($proxy_response_body);
            $response->set_status(201);
            return $response;
        } else {
            $error = json_decode($proxy_response_body, TRUE);
            $response = new WP_REST_Response(array("statusText" => $error, "origin" => "Error Response from Giving Services"));
            $response->set_status($proxy_response_code);
            return $response;
        }
    }
}
```

**UPDATED TO INCLUDE API CALL FROM REACT APPLICATION**

I'm using the [`Fetch Api`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API) within a React Application that is being added to the page via a script.

```
fetch(proxy, {
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    },
    body: JSON.stringify(data)
})
.then(checkStatus)
.then(parseJSON)
.then(json=>{
    const msg = json;
    self.props.submitForm({msg, data})
}).catch(error=>{
    logError({error});
    this.setState({submitting: false})
});
```

**HELPER FUNCTIONS**

```
function logError({error}) {
    console.error(JSON.stringify(error, null, 5))
    if (error.status >= 500) {
        alert('There was an internal error submitting your form. Please check your information and try again or call us at PRIVATE');
    }
}

function checkStatus(response) {
    console.log({response})
    if (response.status >= 200 && response.status < 300) {
        return response
    } else {
        var error = new Error(response.statusText)
        error.response = response
        error.status = response.status
        throw error
    }
}

function parseJSON(response) {
    return response.json()
}
```

Comment: What happens when you disable the `handle_preflight()` (comment out the `add_action()`)? Does the 400 error persist?

Comment: @SallyCJ Yes. It persists.

Comment: Then it shouldn't be a pre-flight issue. Perhaps the request body was empty or not a valid JSON string? See the `is_null($data)` in the `proxy_data()` function. Try temporarily change the `$response->set_status(400);` to `$response->set_status(200);` (or use another status other than `400`).. and see if you get the `200` status. If yes, then the problem was probably with the request body.

Comment: That's not the issue either. I tried what you said, same response, but I could also tell that from the lack of the full error (statusText, origin) in the logged error. The errors I define within my function include extra information so that I know the error is generated by a particular issue with the submitted data. Even so, I changed the 400 to 200 and still got the 400 error.

Comment: "*application on my wordpress site that calls this api*" - is it possible for you to share the code the application uses when making the API request?

Comment: Sure. I've added the JS I use to call the api

Comment: Just found my problem.

Comment: Ok, but maybe you should write an answer (and accept it), or update your question, so that people know the question has been answered. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There were three problems I discovered with my code above.

First, `$_SERVER["HTTP_REFERRER"];` is an undefined index, moreover it is mispelled - `HTTP_REFERER` would be correct if it could be accessed this way in WP. I found `get_http_origin()` instead.

```
$data['UrlReferer'] = get_http_origin();
```

Second, I also mispelled the field I was saving this variable to - `UrlReferrer` (bad), `UrlReferer` (correct), something only I could have detected by testing on my end. But I wouldn't have caught this if I didn't catch the first.

Third, I dropped `$data['ClientBrowser'] = $_SERVER["HTTP_USER_AGENT"];` since I can get that client side.

**UPDATE**

I can also get the URL referrer from the client side as well, by passing `window.location.href` to the api.

Comment: +1 :). PHP should make `HTTP_REFERER` and `HTTP_REFERRER` work interchangably! XD